# React Slick overlapping images

Tags: css, responsive, react-slick

So I've been using `react-slick` for a while, but one problem remains the same.
I have a screen-wide carousel which shows 1 slide at a time. When I open the dev-tools window(hence - decreasing width), the previous slide overlaps the current with the exact width the dev-tools window is. Here is a screenshot to better understand the issue:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2zn3.jpg).

The right behavior for a responsive component is to change its width and height according to screen size changes. Can anyone tell me what am I missing here or how to resolve this problem?